# Values of 'n' for $n^{2019}+20$ to be divisible $n^2+n+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility, integers

For how many integers $n$, $n^2+n+1$ is a divisor of $n^{2019}+20$?

Could someone give me some hint to proceed in this question? $n=-1,0,1$ are the values obtained by hit and trial but how to get all values?

Comment: My usual approach works only with the help of [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialExtendedGCD%5Bn%5E2019%2B20,n2%2Bn%2B1,n%5D). The approach with [resultants](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Resultant%5Bn%5E2019%2B20,n2%2Bn%2B1,n%5D) works but it gives $441$ not $21$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$n^{2019}+20=n^{2019}-1+21=(n^3)^{673}-1+21=$$
$$=(n^3-1)\left(n^{2016}+...+1\right)+21=(n-1)(n^2+n+1)\left(n^{2016}+...+1\right)+21,$$
which says that $\frac{21}{n^2+n+1}\in\mathbb Z$ and an the rest is  easy checking.

I got $\{-5,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,4\}$.

Comment: How is $(n^{2019}-1)/(n^2+n+1)$ an integer?  Please show for a complete solution.

Comment: I meant, in the answer.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi Is it now good?

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

If $n^3-1=(n-1)(n^2+n+1)=0\implies n^3=?$

$n^{2019}=(n^3)^{673}=?$

Comment: (+1) I was working on an answer along these lines. You were faster.

Comment: You need to use modulo signs here. $n^3-1\equiv $ $(n-1)(n^2+n+1)\equiv $ $0\pmod{n^2+n+1}$ $\implies n^3\equiv $ $ ?\pmod{n^2+n+1}$, $n^{2019}\equiv (n^3)^{673}$ $\equiv ?$ $\pmod{n^2+n+1}$.